# Un-ignore folder in SmartSVN

Tags: svn, ignore, svnignore, smartsvn

I'm trying to un-ignore a file I specifically ignored in SmartSVN. Documentation seems good in terms of how to ignore files, but I can't figure out how to un-ignore them.

I looked for a .svnignore file, but I couldn't find it (I'm much more familiar with git than SVN, so if I'm looking in the wrong place, please let me know!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the parent directory of the file, use **Properties|Ignore Patterns** and remove the file (or pattern) from the list.